# TFS2015 - WorkItemChangedEvent - WCF webservice - No changes recorded on "Tags"

Tags: c#, plugins, tfs, server-side

I have implemented a workitemchangedevent as a WCF service as described [here](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/02/how-to-use-wcf-to-subscribe-to-the-tfs-2010-event-service-rolling-up-hours.aspx) on our TFS2015 (update 2) server.

This is all working fine, except for 1 thing.
The 'Tags' which you can define on a workitem (feature, user story, ...), are not listed in the changedfields collection, when doing an update to this field.

Is this by design? Or is this due to the fact that I'm using a WCF service and not a real server side plugin (application tier/webservices/bin/plugins)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe tags existed when the WCF API was written and I know they do not update the old API endpoints with new features afterwards. You should look at the newer TFS SDKs if you need newer features. They have switched from WCF to REST and the client SDK wraps that. The new methodologies are much easier to work with then bidsubscribes and the like.

For subscription stuff I think you want WebHooks actually https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/service-hooks/services/webhooks

Here's some code I previously wrote for creating a subscription to get build success from code instead of the web interface, my receiver was also a wcf.

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;

public void CreateWebHookBuildSubscription( string teamProject,string buildDefinitionName,string eventType = "build.complete",string status = "Succeeded",string apiVersion = "1.0" )
    {
        if (ConfigAccessBase.GetConfigBool( "EnableContinuousIntegration" ))
        {
            try
            {
                VssConnection connection = new VssConnection( _tfsCollectionBaseUrl, new VssCredentials( true ) );
                ProjectHttpClient pClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
                TeamProjectReference project = pClient.GetProject( teamProject, false, false, null ).Result;

                RestRequest checkSubsRequest = new RestRequest( "_apis/hooks/subscriptions/?api-version=" + apiVersion, Method.GET );
                checkSubsRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                checkSubsRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
                var checkSubResponse = tfsRestClient.Execute( checkSubsRequest );
                TFSListSubscriptionsResponse listSubResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TFSListSubscriptionsResponse>( checkSubResponse.Content );
                if (checkSubResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    WriteLogEntry( checkSubResponse, EventTypes.Errors, "Error in TFSWebHook.CreateWebHookBuildSubscription when calling TFS to get existing subscription list: " + checkSubResponse.ErrorMessage + " " + checkSubResponse.ErrorException.ToString() );
                    return;
                }
                string notificationUrl = ConfigAccessBase.GetConfig( "ServiceBaseUrl" ) + @"/Remoting.asmx/ReceieveTFSBuildSuccessNotification";
                if (listSubResponse.count == 0 || !listSubResponse.value.Any( x =>
                    x.publisherInputs.buildStatus.ToLower().Equals( status.ToLower() )
                    && x.eventType.ToLower().Equals( eventType.ToLower() )
                    && x.publisherInputs.definitionName.ToLower().Equals( buildDefinitionName.ToLower() )
                    && x.publisherInputs.projectId.Equals( project.Id.ToString() )
                    && x.consumerInputs.url.ToLower().Equals( notificationUrl.ToLower() ) ))
                {
                    WriteLogEntry( checkSubResponse, EventTypes.Informational, "TFSWebHook.CreateWebHookBuildSubscription creating a new build notification web hook subscription in TFS: TeamProject: " + project.Name + " Definition: " + buildDefinitionName + " Status: " + status );
                    SubscribeToTFSBuildRequest request = new SubscribeToTFSBuildRequest()
                    {
                        publisherId = "tfs",
                        eventType = eventType,
                        consumerId = "webHooks",
                        consumerActionId = "httpRequest",
                        resourceVersion = "1.0",
                        publisherInputs = new TFS.WebApi.Lib.PublisherInputs()
                        {
                            buildStatus = status,
                            definitionName = buildDefinitionName,
                            projectId = project.Id.ToString()
                        },
                        consumerInputs = new TFS.WebApi.Lib.ConsumerInputs
                        {
                            url = notificationUrl
                        }
                    };
                    RestRequest createSubReq = new RestRequest( "_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=" + apiVersion, Method.POST );
                    createSubReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    createSubReq.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
                    createSubReq.AddJsonBody( request );
                    var createSubResponse = tfsRestClient.Execute( createSubReq );

                    if (createSubResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        WriteLogEntry( createSubResponse, EventTypes.Errors, "Error in TFSWebHook.CreateWebHookBuildSubscription when calling TFS to create a subscription: " + createSubResponse.ErrorMessage + " " + createSubResponse.ErrorException.ToString() );
                        return;
                    }
                    //dont actually need any data
                    //SubscribeToTFSBuildResponse subscribeResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubscribeToTFSBuildResponse>( createSubResponse.Content );
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLogException( ex );
            }
        }     
    }
```